# Looping through a JSON array problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

So I've got an ajax call which returns this array:

```
    [
      {
        "id":"47",
        "description":"Or pancakes?",
        "source":"",
        "uncut_url":"uploads\/uncut\/IMG_20140221_100557.jpg",
        "300_url":"uploads\/300\/IMG_20140221_100557.jpg",
        "600_url":"uploads\/600\/IMG_20140221_100557.jpg",
        "created":"2014-03-07 15:01:41"
      },
      {
        "id":"46",
        "description":"Who doesnt like eggs benedict?",
        "source":"",
        "uncut_url":"uploads\/uncut\/2014-02-20 08.40.26.jpg",
        "300_url":"uploads\/300\/2014-02-20 08.40.26.jpg",
        "600_url":"uploads\/600\/2014-02-20 08.40.26.jpg",
        "created":"2014-03-07 15:00:15"
      }
    ]
```

I'd like to add it into a div which I plan on doing with $().append();

so far I've got this:

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_images.php",
            data: {offset: img_no},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
              $.each(data, function(index, item){

                alert(data);
                $( "#maincontainer" ).append( "<div class='imgcontain'>" );
                $( "#maincontainer" ).append( "<img class='thumb' src='"+data.300_url+"' />" );
                $( "#maincontainer" ).append( "</div>" );
          });
```

So I'd like to loop through the array, an do something with each item in the array, but I can't get it right, so far the alert just says "[object, Object]" and does so twice. 
I'm sure there's an easy solution to this and I'm just not seeing it, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: change `$( "#maincontainer" ).append( "<img class='thumb' src='"+data.300_url+"' />" );` to $( "#maincontainer" ).append( "<img class='thumb' src='"+item.300_url+"' />" );

Comment: you can also use `$( "#maincontainer" ).append( "<img class='thumb' src='"+data[index].300_url+"' />" );`

Comment: If you want to access properties that start with digits, you have to use bracket notation. And of course you have to access the right object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `data` is what you're iterating over (which is why it shows it twice, you have two items in your data), and debugging with `alert()` is not going to be very helpful. Try putting it in a `console.log()` statement.

However, the solution to your problem is to replace `data` in the `$.each` function with `item` :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your suggestions, using the console does make it heaps easier. So I havn't changed anything except for now I'm using console.log(item.id); console.log(item.description); which works fine, except when I add console.log(item.300_url); then is throws an error 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL' on that line, any idea why?

Comment: So after much console logging I worked out I can reference each item with item['id'] etc. So while I didn't exactly use your answer it certainly put me on the right track, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append) does not work like string concatenation.

When you say `$( "#maincontainer" ).append( "<div class='imgcontain'>" )` create creates and closes the target div element so the `img` will be created as a sibling instead of as a descendant.

Also you need to use `item` to refer current item in the array inside the iteration callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_images.php",
    data: {
        offset: img_no
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var array = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            array.push("<div class='imgcontain'>");
            //need to use item to refer current item
            array.push("<img class='thumb' src='" + item.300_url + "' />");
            array.push("</div>");
        });

        $("#maincontainer").append(array.join(''));
    }
})
```

An array based solution is used here because it limits the number of dom manipulations